# Parse String date in (yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.S) format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I want the Input string which is of pattern "yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss.S" to be converted to Date.
The Input string is 1988.07.29 12:12:12.123

I have done it in the following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(value);
```

I get ParseException saying the entered date is unparseable.

First Thing, does my pattern correspond to the Input string? If yes what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use colons instead of dots in the pattern:

```
yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.S
```

Characters from `A` to `Z` and from `a` to `z` are interpreted as special characters. All other characters in the pattern are matched as they are. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more details.